# Regex: find out first coordinate from a string of list of coordianates

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string

`"Polygon((85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253,84.79588729053454 27.769298229948298,84.7943200187415 27.5526903779245,85.0474690397788 27.55101288321816,85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253))"`

I would like to get the first coordinate (in this case :85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253). To achieve the longitude value of 85.04953560330497 I executed a regex

`\(\d{2}\.\d{5}` and then got `var str = (85.04953` and later did `str.split('(');` to finally get only the number.

But the problem is with Latitude `(27.5526903779245)`. What should I do to find out the first latitude. The problem is the number of decimal places are not fixed i.e. Here there are 13 digits after decimal in longitude`(85.04953560330497)`, but could be any number and cannot use digits after space (because there are other numbers too after space like `(27.769298229948298)`.

I am a beginner to regex please help me find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
\((\d+\.\d+)\s(\d+\.\d+)
```

[regex DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dS9fB3/2)

and get numbers by calling captured groups like:

```
var str = "Polygon((85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253,84.79588729053454 27.769298229948298,84.7943200187415 27.5526903779245,85.0474690397788 27.55101288321816,85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253))"
var regex = /\((\d+.\d+)\s(\d+.\d+)/;
var match = regex.exec(str);
var a = match[1];
var b = match[2];
```

[jsDEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m0skjkgn/)

Answer (score 2):

Use two groupings

```
var str = "Polygon((85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253,84.79588729053454 27.769298229948298,84.7943200187415 27.5526903779245,85.0474690397788 27.55101288321816,85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253))"
str.match(/(\d+.\d+)\s(\d+.\d+)/);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following *RegExp*

```
var re = /(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/;

var str = "Polygon((85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253,84.79588729053454 27.769298229948298,84.7943200187415 27.5526903779245,85.0474690397788 27.55101288321816,85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253))"
str.match(re); // ["85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253", "85.04953560330497", "27.767605311484253"]
               //   whole match,                            first group,         second group
```

---

If you want to find all of them, you could use a `g` flag, but with the string you have it looks easier to simply trim off `Polygon((` and `))` then `str.split` on `,`s

---

```
(pattern)    Capture group, remembers match for pattern, lets you treat it as one item
(?:pattern)  Non-capture group, forgets match for pattern, lets you treat it as one item
x?           Matching (item) x is optional, greedy
x??          Matching (item) x is optional, non-greedy (not used here)
x+           Match at least one repeat of (item) x, greedy
x+?          Match at least one repeat of (item) x, non-greedy (not used here)
\d           Digit, same as [0-9]
\s           Whitespace, i.e. spaces, tabs, new lines, etc
\.           A literal ".", rather than wildcard (which is what . usually means)
/pattern/ig  pattern is a RegExp literal, i and g are flags
\/           A literal "/", rather than terminating the RegExp literal
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Depending on how regular the co-ordinates are, it could be as simple as

```
\([\d\.]+
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you always want to extract the first two coordinates, setting the comma character as a boundary:

```
var m = s.match(/Polygon\(\((\d+\.\d+)\s(\d+\.\d+),/),
   longitude = m[1],
   latitude = m[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the first item of this match:

```
    str = str.match(/(-?\d{1,2}\.\d+ ?){2}/)[0];
    // === "85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253"
```

Explanation:

```
/
    (            // capturing group
        -?       // a minus if present (west/south of 0/0)
        \d{1,2}  // one or two digits
        \.       // definitely a decimal point
        \d+      // at least one digit
        ␣?       // an optional trailing single space
    ){2}         // two singleton float coordinates
/
```

Answer (score 2):

No regex solution:

```
var string = "Polygon((85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253,84.79588729053454 27.769298229948298,84.7943200187415 27.5526903779245,85.0474690397788 27.55101288321816,85.04953560330497 27.767605311484253))";
var latlng = string.replace("Polygon((", "").replace("))", "").split(",")[0].split(" ");
latlng // ["85.04953560330497", "27.767605311484253"]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case the space is a separator between a longitude / latitude pair.
If you expect the string to be this constant format, then you only have to
worry about defining a proper decimal number regex.

This is the only regex I know of to validate a positive integer or decimal
number -

```
 (?:
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  
      \. \d+ 
 )
```

Then just add capture buffers and put it in the format you need.

```
 #  (\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)[ ](\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)

 (                             # (1 start), longitude
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  
      \. \d+ 
 )                             # (1 end)
 [ ]                           # space
 (                             # (2 start), latitude
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d* )?
   |  
      \. \d+ 
 )                             # (2 end)
```